# How to make my sails app to use local js and css dependencies in dev and cdn in prod?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ejs

I want to use cdn for something like bootstrap, jquery in production mode. But in local development, I still want to use auto inject js and css dependencies. How can I do it automatically?

I know the following snippet can distinct production and development environment.

```
<% if (sails.config.environment === 'production') { %>
<!-- prod script tags go here -->
<% } else  {
    // Client-side Javascript in development
    // ========================
%>
<!-- whether you're using the linker or not, dev scripts could go here -->
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
<% } %>
```

However, not all the inject js is for development. I only want those vendor's scripts to be injected for development. But my custom scripts like angular controllers should be injected for both production and development.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in config/local.js and config/env sort of do their job, but it’s not enough for environment variables.

What we really need is a place to store all of our config variables regardless if we are in a development, testing, or production environment. The answer is simple: use dotenv. This will load a .env file or look for environment variables on the machine.

Start by pulling it into the Sails.js project and following the dotenv docs:

```
$ npm install dotenv --save
Then require dotenv in app.js and load the .env file:

var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
```

Create a .env and put some vars in it:

```
environment= PRODUCTION
```

Now you can access those environment variables anywhere in the app (probably in some config/ files):

```
console.log(process.env.PRODUCTION);
```

Comment: in your example, you echo PRODUCTION when you set in the example environment. you don't echo the value, you echo the param name you set, in your example, environment.